# How to make contents of absolutely positioned containers enclose within container

Tags: html, css, absolute

I am trying to code this page using CSS however cannot get it right.

Basically what I want is to have 4 ad container each having item image, some text and the price. The 4 ad containers should scale to  full width and height.

The problem is when I define ad containers as absolutely positioned (and position them as below) and then define contents of the container as relatively positioned then contents gets relatively positioned to the viewport not their respective containers.

Can somebody help in correcting the css so that all four container fill full webpage and have the contents relatively positioned to their respective containers. Even if one of the containers were removed the other three 3 should occupy the same position. Here is an Image representation:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="ad1_wrapper">
    <div id="ad1_bgimg">
        <img src="<?php echo get_option('ad1_bgimg'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div id="ad1_productimg">
        <img src="<?php echo get_option('ad1_productimg'); ?>" class="fadeInUp" />
    </div>

    <div id="ad1_tagline">
        <p class="option-tagline"><?php echo get_option('ad1_tagline'); ?></p>
    </div>              


    <div id="ad1_discount">
        <p class="option-discount"><?php echo get_option('ad1_discount'); ?></p>
    </div>

    <div id="ad1_offerdate" class="option-offerdate">
        <p><?php echo get_option('ad1_offerdate'); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*wrapper*/
#ad1_wrapper,  
#ad2_wrapper, 
#ad3_wrapper,
#ad4_wrapper { 
    width:50%; 
    height:50%; 
    position:absolutely; 
    top:0; 
    left:0;
}


#ad2_wrapper {top:0;left:50%;}
#ad3_wrapper {top:50%;left:0%;}
#ad4_wrapper {top:50%;left:50%;}


/*ad1 elements*/
    #ad1_bgimg, 
    #ad1_productimg, 
    #ad2_discount, 
    #ad4_punchline {
        position:relative; 
        top:0; 
        left:0;
    }
```

Comment: It's `position: absolute` not `absolutely`

Answer (score 0):

If it's supposed to be tabular then use a table.

Comment: Table layouts are looked down on.

Answer (score 0):

As @somethinghere have told on his comment. There is an error on your css. Its `position: absolute;`

To place the divs inside a container, you could do as below. I have put borders on the divs so its easier to see.

```css
#ad1_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  
}

.with-border{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 49%; // I've put 49% here because of the borders. If you have no borders in your divs, you can set it to 50%.
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="ad1_wrapper">
    <div class="with-border" id="ad1_bgimg">
        <img src="<?php echo get_option('ad1_bgimg'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="with-border" id="ad1_productimg">
        <img src="<?php echo get_option('ad1_productimg'); ?>" class="fadeInUp" />
    </div>

    <div class="with-border" id="ad1_tagline">
        <p class="option-tagline"><?php echo get_option('ad1_tagline'); ?></p>
    </div>              


    <div class="with-border" id="ad1_discount">
        <p class="option-discount"><?php echo get_option('ad1_discount'); ?></p>
    </div>

    <div class="with-border" id="ad1_offerdate" class="option-offerdate">
        <p><?php echo get_option('ad1_offerdate'); ?></p>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

This way, if some of the divs is gone, the following one will take its place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's `position: absolute;`

Second of all, you've got CSS rules for `#ad` 2, 3 and 4 `_wrapper` when the elements don't exist.

Demo:

```css
.ad{
  
  /* Important stuff */
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  /* Making it look nice */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  
}
#ad1{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
#ad2{
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
#ad3{
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}
#ad4{
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  background: lime;
}
.text{
  /* Not important stuff */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='ad1' class='ad'>
  <p class='text'>Some Text Some Text</p>
</div>

<div id='ad2' class='ad'>
  <p class='text'>Some Text Some Text</p>
</div>

<div id='ad3' class='ad'>
  <p class='text'>Some Text Some Text</p>
</div>

<div id='ad4' class='ad'>
  <p class='text'>Some Text Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/ay34L84g/).

The four panels will re-size based on the `#container` element's size. While the inner attributes (taglines, etc...) will be positioned relatively to the container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="ad1_wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div id="ad1_productimg" class="productImg"><img src="#" class="fadeInUp" /></div>
      <div id="ad1_tagline" class="tagline"><p class="option-tagline">Tagline</p></div>  
      <div id="ad1_discount" class="discount"><p class="option-discount">Discount</p></div>
      <div id="ad1_offerdate" class="optionOfferdate"><p>Offerdate</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ad2_wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div id="ad1_productimg" class="productImg"><img src="#" class="fadeInUp" /></div>
      <div id="ad1_tagline" class="tagline"><p class="option-tagline">Tagline</p></div>  
      <div id="ad1_discount" class="discount"><p class="option-discount">Discount</p></div>
      <div id="ad1_offerdate" class="optionOfferdate"><p>Offerdate</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ad3_wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div id="ad1_productimg" class="productImg"><img src="#" class="fadeInUp" /></div>
      <div id="ad1_tagline" class="tagline"><p class="option-tagline">Tagline</p></div>  
      <div id="ad1_discount" class="discount"><p class="option-discount">Discount</p></div>
      <div id="ad1_offerdate" class="optionOfferdate"><p>Offerdate</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ad4_wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div id="ad1_productimg" class="productImg"><img src="#" class="fadeInUp" /></div>
      <div id="ad1_tagline" class="tagline"><p class="option-tagline">Tagline</p></div>  
      <div id="ad1_discount" class="discount"><p class="option-discount">Discount</p></div>
      <div id="ad1_offerdate" class="optionOfferdate"><p>Offerdate</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Container */
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
}

/*wrapper*/
#ad1_wrapper,
#ad2_wrapper,
#ad3_wrapper,
#ad4_wrapper {
    width:50%;height:50%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#ad2_wrapper {top:0;left:50%;background: red;}
#ad3_wrapper {top:50%;left:0%;background: green;}
#ad4_wrapper {top:50%;left:50%;background: purple;}

#container .innerWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.productImg,
.tagline,
.discount,
.optionOfferdate {
    position: absolute;
}

.productImg {bottom: 0px; right: 0px;}
.tagline {top: 20px; left: 20px;}
.discount {top: 40px; left: 40px;}
.optionOfferdate {bottom: 0px; left: 30px;}
```